# Django: Referencing inherited attributes from mixin

Tags: python, django

I have a long list of tuples used as model choices. They are currently class attributes in a model definition. I would like to move them into a mixin without affecting existing references across a legacy codebase.

Here is what currently exists:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    COLD = 1
    WARM = 2
    HOT = 3
    FIRE = 4

    STATUSES = (
        (COLD, 'Cold'),
        (WARM, 'Warm'),
        (HOT, 'Hot'),
        (FIRE, 'Fire'),
    )

   status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSES)
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```py
class StatusMixin:
    COLD = 1
    WARM = 2
    HOT = 3
    FIRE = 4

    STATUSES = (
        (COLD, 'Cold'),
        (WARM, 'Warm'),
        (HOT, 'Hot'),
        (FIRE, 'Fire'),
    )

class MyModel(StatusMixin, models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSES)
```

I'm trying to reference them:

1. As part of the model inheriting them:

```py
my_model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
if my_model_instance.status == MyModel.FIRE:
    return
```

2. As part of a model NOT inheriting them, but referencing the model that does:

```py
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    my_model_status = models.IntegerField(choices=MyModel.STATUSES)
```

I am unable to satisfy both conditions. I'm sure there is a better way -- perhaps not a mixin?

Answer (score 0):

If you write it like the following both of your conditions will work:

```
class StatusMixin:
    COLD = 1
    WARM = 2
    HOT = 3
    FIRE = 4

    STATUSES = (
        (COLD, 'Cold'),
        (WARM, 'Warm'),
        (HOT, 'Hot'),
        (FIRE, 'Fire'),
    )

class MyModel(models.Model, StatusMixin):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=StatusMixin.STATUSES)

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    my_model_status = models.IntegerField(choices=MyModel.STATUSES)
```

However I would recommend you to also use `StatusMixin` on `OtherModel`:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model, StatusMixin):
    my_model_status = models.IntegerField(choices=StatusMixin.STATUSES)
```